# Win32API Ruby LoadError

Tags: winapi, ruby, dll

Пытаюсь загрузить при помощи класса Win32API библиотеку basszxtune.dll, но при попытке получаю ошибку LoadError (Было опробовано в Ruby 1.9.2 и Ruby 2.4.5)

Код был написан такой:

```
require 'win32api'
File.exist?("basszxtune.dll") #=> true
player = Win32API.new("basszxtune.dll", "BASS_ZXTUNE_StreamCreateFile", 'ppppp' ,'i')
p player

system 'pause'
```

Ошибка выводится такая.

```
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/2.4.0/fiddle.rb:47:in `initialize': No such file or directory (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/2.4.0/fiddle.rb:47:in `new'
    from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/2.4.0/fiddle.rb:47:in `dlopen'
    from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32api.rb:28:in `rescue in initialize'
    from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/2.4.0/win32api.rb:24:in `initialize'
    from C:/Users/Татьяна/Documents/RPGVXAce/project1/System/start.rb:3:in `new'
    from C:/Users/Татьяна/Documents/RPGVXAce/project1/System/start.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Дополню, что файл библиотеки лежит в той же папке что и исполняемый .rb файл

Comment: `C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/2.4.0/fiddle.rb:47` -- что в этой строке? Если там фигурирует переменная с путем к искомому файлу, вставить туда print. М.б. что `Win32API.new` не в working dir смотрит, а в какое-нить `c:/Windows`. И если так, то я бы попробовал, например, указать путь к длл-ке полностью.

Comment: В том .rb файле вызывает ошибку следующая строка  ```Fiddle::Handle.new library``` в переменной ```library``` записываются такие строки ```"kernel32.dll" "basszxtune.dll"```